# Run function with arguments inside of a standard hook

Tags: emacs, hook

What is the best way to run a function taking arguments, eg. one that would normally be run with `run-hook-with-args`, inside a normal hook, eg. `after-save-hook`.

As a simple example, I want to add `some-function` to `after-save-hook` here, but allow it to have an additional argument.

```
(defun some-function (&optional arg)
  (if arg 'do-this 'otherwise-do-this))

;; how to run `some-function' with argument here?
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'some-function nil 'local)
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Yes, use `run-hook-with-args`. What's the question? Define "best way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've got something like this (I've changed the function name to make it less confusing).

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-function nil 'local)
```

But you're asking how you can arrange that when `after-save-hook` calls `my-function` it passes an argument to it.

Firstly, you can't do that directly, for the probably-obvious reason that `after-save-hook` is a normal hook and therefore gets run in a way that doesn't provide any facility for passing arguments.

That means you have to add to the hook a function which *actually does what you want*.

You *could* create a function which does what you want like so:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (apply-partially 'my-function ARG) nil 'local)
```

But approaches along these lines are really messy when it comes to inspecting and manipulating the hook later, so I recommend not doing anything like this.

Honestly, the cleanest approach is very simply to define a named function which does what you want, and add *that* to the hook.

```
(defun my-function-do-this ()
  "Do This"
  'do-this)

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-function-do-this nil 'local)
```

Comment: nice, I had forgot about `appy-partially`. I don't see how your recommended approach would work though, as it doesn't take an argument. I understand why its messy and not generally good to hook unamed functions

Comment: My recommend approach doesn't *need* to take an argument; it just does the thing which your original function was going to do when you passed it an argument. i.e. where you wrote`(if arg 'do-this 'otherwise-do-this)`

Comment: If you wanted to, `my-function-do-this` could call `(my-function ARG)`.

Comment: I see, in my case though I actually want to use the value of the argument , not just have a branch on its existence

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your requirement, because I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: no worries, you've given me plenty to work with. I was headed down the wrong path trying to wrap the function, when apply-partially already does what I wanted. Having additional functions may be better as well, thanks!